# Predicting a breakdown probability in a time window using machine learning classification in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I want to predict breakdowns of a machine. The data I have is on a daily basis and contains info like "minutes in operation", "number of external shocks" or "operator name". I created additional factors to store time-dependent data, i.e. "accumulated minutes in operation since last break down". See below df as an idea what the data looks like

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{"date" : ["2019/04/24" , "2019/04/25", "2019/04/26", "2019/04/27", "2019/04/28"],
"minutes in operation" : [200, 200, 200, 200, 200],
"accumulated minutes in operation since last break down" : [200, 400, 600, 800, 1000],
"breakdown" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]},
index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

The idea is that using machine learning correctly classifies breakdown-days from non-breakdown-days. The prediction is poor on a daily basis which is not particularly bad as I don´t need to predict "It is going to fail on that specific day". It would be great if I could predict it is going to "fail within the next three days".

Therefore I consider 2 solutions:

1. Label the 2 days prior the event as "1" ("breakdown" : [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]). With that I yield very good prediction results.
2. Aggregate 3 consecutive days to one observation row and do the predictions on the aggregated level.

I´m wondering if this is the correct way to predict "occurrence of event in a time window of 3 days" or if there is a more ML-pythonic way of doing it.

Comment: Haven't worked with time series data that much but I don't see any reason not to try **2**. Also, what kind of model are you planning to use for the task? (logistic, nb, etc.)

Comment: You can check [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms) for an overview of machine learning related Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: anddt: Want to use XGB, RF, Log Reg, KNN and SVC. Disadvantage of 2 is taht I "lose" number of observations and it will be a bit harder to aggregate certain data points. 

AMC: Thanks for pointing this out. Didn´t understand there was a larger stackexchange concept in the background and SO is just a part of it

Thanks to both of you for the help